# What is the best one word reply to "a bit late" message?

Tags: word-request, politeness

My manager and I have a scheduled one-on-one meeting and just before the meeting time, he sent me a message, "a bit late".

I do not care if he is late and it is very courtesy of him sending me this message, I immediately replied, "sure".

But now I think that is the wrong word, or at least there should be a better one.

For sure I can say, "no worry", "no problem", etc., but I am looking for an one-word reply and I think "ok" is just too plain.

Any suggestion?

[**UPDATE**]
I am not angry or upset, on the contrary the message I'd like to deliver is, do not worry, I am not bothered by your being late at all. Or maybe even a little bit of "take your time".

Comment: How about: understood, waiting, fine (if you are angry about it)?

Comment: "no problem". When texting, this is often abbreviated as "np".

Comment: @ctol: you should not send "np" to any boss. Or any other abbreviation, for that matter, unless the abbreviation is really common and well understood in the company

Answer (score 2):

**No worries** or **no problem** both work perfectly here. The issue with a one-word response is that brevity over text can easily be interpreted as being annoyed or otherwise upset with the person you're talking to.

There are a number of ways you can soften a short **okay** to convey the proper meaning, however. This is less the realm of proper, conventional English, and more the realm of complicated text etiquette. Essentially, you need to add something that conveys the appropriate tone. "Okay!" is perfectly acceptable, and "Okay :)" may be seen as a bit informal, due to the smiley face, in business settings, but is not entirely unheard of.

Unfortunately, there is no one word in English that will easily convey everything you want to put into this text. If your goal is ultimate clarity, something like

> No worries, take your time

is still quite a bit more than one word, but will leave little room for misinterpretation.